# Calculus between Two multivariable Gaussain pdfs

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-integral

I tried to get the product of Multivariate Gausssian pdf.

In [8.1.8](http://compbio.fmph.uniba.sk/vyuka/ml/old/2008/handouts/matrix-cookbook.pdf), this says 
\begin{align*}
G(x-v_i, \Sigma_i) \times G(x-v_j, \Sigma_j) = G(v_i-v_j, \Sigma_i+\Sigma_j) G(x-v, \Sigma)   \\ 
= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{1/2} |\Sigma_i+\Sigma_j|^{1/2}}  \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} (v_i - v_j)^T (\Sigma_i+\Sigma_j)^{-1} (v_i - v_j)  \right\}  G(x-v, \Sigma)
\end{align*}

However, my answer is as follows:

At first, suppose that
\begin{align}
G(x-v_i, \Sigma_i) &= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d/2} |\Sigma_i|^{1/2}}  \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} (x - v_i)^T (\Sigma_i)^{-1} (x - v_i)  \right\}   \\
&=  \exp\left\{ -\frac{d}{2}\log(2\pi) -\frac{1}{2}\log|\Sigma_i|   -\frac{1}{2} (x - v_i)^T (\Sigma_i)^{-1} (x - v_i)  \right\}  \\
&= \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} \left[  d\log(2\pi) +\log|\Sigma_i|  + (x - v_i)^T (\Sigma_i)^{-1} (x - v_i) \right] \right\}  \\
&=  \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} \left[  d\log(2\pi) +\log|\Sigma_i|  +  x^T \Sigma_i^{-1}x - 2x^T\Sigma_i^{-1}v_i +  v_i^T\Sigma_i^{-1}v_i   \right] \right\}   \\
&= \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} x^T \Sigma_i^{-1}x + x^T\Sigma_i^{-1}v_i  -\frac{1}{2} \left[  d\log(2\pi) +\log|\Sigma_i| +  v_i^T\Sigma_i^{-1}v_i   \right] \right\}   \\
&= \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} x^T \Sigma_i^{-1}x + x^T\Sigma_i^{-1}v_i \right\}    \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} \left[  d\log(2\pi) +\log|\Sigma_i| +  v_i^T\Sigma_i^{-1}v_i   \right] \right\}  \\
&=  \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} x^T \Sigma_i^{-1}x + x^T\eta_i \right\}    \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} \left[  d\log(2\pi) +\log|\Sigma_i| +  \eta_i^T\Sigma_i\eta_i   \right] \right\}  \\
&=  \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} x^T \Sigma_i^{-1}x + x^T\eta_i + \zeta_i \right\}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\eta_i = \Sigma_i^{-1} v_i  \\
\zeta_i =  -\frac{1}{2} \left[  d\log(2\pi) +\log|\Sigma_i| +  \eta_i^T\Sigma_i\eta_i   \right] 
\end{align}

Let's calculate

\begin{align}
G(x-v_i, \Sigma_i) \times G(x-v_j, \Sigma_j) 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
&= \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} x^T \Sigma_i^{-1}x + x^T\eta_i + \zeta_i \right\}  \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} x^T \Sigma_j^{-1}x + x^T\eta_j + \zeta_j \right\}    \\
&=  \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} x^T (\Sigma_i^{-1}+\Sigma_j^{-1})x + x^T(\eta_i+\eta_j) + \zeta_i + \zeta_j \right\}  \\
&= \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} x^T \Sigma^{-1}x + x^T\eta + \zeta - \zeta + \zeta_i + \zeta_j \right\}   \\
&=  \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} x^T \Sigma^{-1}x + x^T\eta + \zeta  \right\} \exp\left\{ - \zeta + \zeta_i + \zeta_j \right\}   \\
&= G(x-v, \Sigma)  \exp\left\{ - \zeta + \zeta_i + \zeta_j \right\}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\Sigma^{-1} = \Sigma_i^{-1}+\Sigma_j^{-1}   \\
\eta = \eta_i+\eta_j  \\
\zeta =  -\frac{1}{2} \left[ d\log(2\pi) +\log|\Sigma| +  \eta^T\Sigma\eta   \right]
\end{align}

I could not derive the following fact:
\begin{align}
\exp\left\{ - \zeta + \zeta_i + \zeta_j \right\} = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{1/2} |\Sigma_i+\Sigma_j|^{1/2}}  \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} (v_i - v_j)^T (\Sigma_i+\Sigma_j)^{-1} (v_i - v_j)  \right\}
\end{align}

Where did I make a mistake?

Thank you in advance.